# How do I calculate polygon area with arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, area

I'd like to develop an application with ArcEngine that can calculate the area of a polygon.

I wrote the below code to select a polygon in a combobox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pmapcontrol2.LayerCount; i++)
{

    Pfeaturelayer = (IFeatureLayer)pmapcontrol2.get_Layer(i);
    if (Pfeaturelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
    {


        cmbfeaturelayer.Items.Add(pmapcontrol2.get_Layer(i).Name);
    }
}
```

But I couldn't write code to calculate `pfeaturelayer` area.
I think I should use `Ilayer` interface and `Ilayer` use `Ifeature` to calculate area not `ifeaturelayer`.

Is there any way to use `Ifeature` for this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link for some sample code that calculates area of selected polygon feature.

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/Area_Example.htm

```
// The example shows how to get the properties for a selected polygon in
// an ArcMap edit session.
public void showPolygonProperties()
{
    //get editor extension
    UID editorUID = new UIDClass();
    editorUID.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
    IEditor editor = m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUID) as IEditor;
    if (editor.SelectionCount != 1)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Start Editor and select one polygon");
        return;
    }
    IEnumFeature selectedFeatures = editor.EditSelection;
    IPoint centerPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
    IPoint labelPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
    IFeature feature = selectedFeatures.Next();
    while (feature != null)
    {
        if (feature.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
        {
            IArea area = feature.Shape as IArea;
            String message = "+++Polygon.IArea properties...\n" +
            "Area = " + area.Area + "\n" +
            "Center.X = " + area.Centroid.X + "\n" +
            "Center.Y = " + area.Centroid.Y + "\n" +
            "LabelPoint.X = " + area.LabelPoint.X + "\n" +
            "LabelPoint.Y = " + area.LabelPoint.Y;
            area.QueryCentroid(centerPoint);
            area.QueryLabelPoint(labelPoint);
            message = message + "\n" + "+++Polygon.IArea Queries..." + "\n" +
            "Center = " + centerPoint.X + "," + centerPoint.Y + "\n" +
            "Label = " + labelPoint.X + "," + labelPoint.Y;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
        feature = selectedFeatures.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you . but this example used editor to calculate area .i'd like to calculate the selected layer in combobox .

Comment: @majid moosavi, Can you elaborate more what you mean by 'calculate the selected layer in combobox'?

Comment: ,i have a combobox and a button .when i click to the button ,the program calculate area of the selected layer in combobox and show the area in messagebox. thanks

Comment: IArea.Area property gives you the area size. If you'd like to compute the combines area of all selected polygons you will need to iterate through a cursor of features and add the areas then display in your control.